# How do I combine javascript variable to jquery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the table `td` texts by using `Jquery` and `javascript`

I have the following

```
//tables contain bunch of tables
  for(var i = 0; i < tables.length ; i ++){
        var table = tables[i];

        $(table 'td').each(function(){   //I know there is something wrong with my selector.
            $(this).text()
        })
```

The `jquery` selector doesn't work in my case. How do I select every td for different table?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What do you expect `table 'td'` to do?

Comment: Your just missing a "+" after the variable table. `$(table + 'td')`

Comment: When you say that `//tables contain bunch of tables`, is `tables` a JS array or a jQuery selection?

Comment: @Shawn31313 You can't concatenate an object with a string (at least to do what's probably expected)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to use the `.find()` method:

```
$(table).find('td').each(function(){
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/jfj47/

Of course, an alternative is to use the "context selector":

```
$("td", table).each(function(){
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/jfj47/1/

Also, if `tables` is just an array (or array-like object) of DOM elements, you don't have to loop and could use:

```
$(tables).find("td").each(function(){
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/jfj47/2/

References:

- `find()`: http://api.jquery.com/find/
- context selector: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/